# Iron Router showing splash page when deployed, works fine on local

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using Meteor 1.0.2.1 and iron:router 1.0.7. I have managed to set up a route for '/' which works fine locally however when I deploy on meteor I get the iron:router splash.

Here is my route:

Router.route('/', {name: 'landing.index'});

and I have a controller called LandingIndex and a template called LandingIndex as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

edit:

The controllers looks as follows:

```
LandingIndexController = RouteController.extend({
   waitOn: function () {
   },

   data: function () {
   },

   action: function () {
     this.render();
   }
});
```

Comment: Please include your controller code.  Are you using `wait` or `waitOn`?

Comment: What happens if you `Router.go('landing.index')` in the browser console?

Comment: @richsilv Added the controller method

Comment: @azium I get : Error: No route found named "landing.index"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you by any chance using Twitter Bootstrap? I ran into this same problem today, non-reproducible on localhost as well. After way too many hours of trying to reproduce this on a remote env with `meteor deploy xxxxx.meteor.com`, I figured out that it was because of a file contained within Twitter Bootstrap. If you straight up download the .zip file of bootstrap and indiscriminately copy its 3 directories into your project (css/ fonts/ js/), `js/npm.js` will be copied along with it.

I think `js/npm.js` is only needed during the build process with Grunt, so I just deleted it. It solved the issue for me, although I'm not sure why...

Comment: That was indeed the issue! I would have NEVER guessed. Thanks alot.

I actually seem to recall seeing an error in browser call on this npm.js ..

Comment: I am having this same issue but without Bootstrap. I am using Foundation.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had duplicate templates. A quick look at the console pointed out the problem.

Comment: that's what it was for me!

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was some files that came from another branch and stayed "untracked" in Git, so I overlook them.

But it looks like [mup](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) deploys everything, so it deployed this incorrect files too. In addition to that, Iron Router must be catching exceptions from other stuff, so it showed its splash page.

Just removed the untracked files and the problem was solved with another deploy!